# static_assert'ion that a long and int are the Same Type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, int, long-integer, static-assert

So I'm taking a variable from one API, we'll call it `long foo` and passing it to another API which takes it as the value: `int bar`.

I'm in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) in which these are effectively the same thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2017

But this will fire:

```
static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(foo), decltype(bar)>);
```

Because even though these are *effectively* the same, they are not the same type. Is there a workaround for this, other than using the numeric limits library to match a `long` to an `int`?

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long))`?

Comment: The types are not the same.  Maybe you want to know if their lengths are the same?

Comment: If you ever want to port your code to other platforms, you should *not* assume that `int` and `long` are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`long` and `int` are different fundamental types.  Even if they are the same size they are not the same type, so `is_same_v` will never be `true`.  If you want you can check their sizes are the same then proceed with

```
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(bar));
```

You can even make sure that `foo` and `bar` are integral types like

```
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(bar) && 
              std::is_integral_v<decltype(foo)> && 
              std::is_integral_v<decltype(bar)>);
```

You can also make sure they have the same signedness like

```
static_assert(sizeof(foo) == sizeof(bar) && 
             std::is_integral_v<decltype(foo)> && 
             std::is_integral_v<decltype(bar)> &&
             std::is_signed_v<decltype(foo)> == std::is_signed_v<decltype(bar)>);
```